How to make modelsim run #10 in ns in testbenches?
I'm trying to run a test bench in which the inputs change every 10 ns, so I used command #10 in the testbench code. However, in the wave form, it appears to change every 10 ps.
How can I change it?

The command vsim -t 1ns <test_name> does the job.
